# Guardar multiples imagenes en una misma entrada de la tabla - codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de guardar varias imagenes en una misma entrada de mi tabla proyectos, compuesta por:

> id, id_empresa,   nombre_proyecto, img, archivos, facturas, fecha

En mi vista tengo para pedir al usuario que inserte las imagenes deseadas:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputClientCompany">Imagen:</label><br>
      <input type="file" name='img[]' multiple="" class="form-control">
        <br>
    <small>Archivos permitidos: jpg,jpeg,png. Tamaño máximo 1mb</small>                                            
    </div>
```

y aquí coloco la funcion de guardar de mi controlador:

```
public function guardar(){

helper(['text','form', 'url']);

$proyectos = new ProyectosModel();

$validacion = $this->validate([
    'nombre_proyecto' => 'required|min_length[3]',
    'id_empresa' => 'required',
    'img' => [
        'uploaded[img]',
        'mime_in[img,image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg]',
        'max_size[img,1024]'
    ]]);

    $nombreRandom = random_string('numeric', 6);

    if (!$validacion){

        $session = session();
        $session->setFlashdata('mensaje','Por favor, revise la información');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
    $nombreRandom = random_string('numeric', 6);
if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('img')) {

     foreach($this->request->getFileMultiple('img') as $file)
     {   
        $nuevoNombre = $nombreRandom . '-' . $file->getName();
        $file->move('./public/assets/img',$nuevoNombre);

      $data = [
        'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
        'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
        'img' =>  $nuevoNombre
      ];

      $proyectos->insert($data);
     }
}

return $this->response->redirect( site_url('/projectList')); 

}
```

Funciona "correctamente" ya que guarda y crea los registros en la base de datos, el problema es que por cada imagen crea una nueva linea, y yo deseo que se guarden todas las imagenes juntas en una miasma columna, dentro ed un array tal vez o algo similar, pero no logro sacarlo.

Como se realizaría? gracias!! si se necesitan mas datos los pongo.

Comment: Consulta, necesitas **si o si** guardar la imagen en la BDD? podría ser mas eficiente hacer un upload de los archivos de imagen y guardar los links en un array, JSON o lo que quieras en modo texto dentro del campo. No sobrecargas la BDD y ni te cuento las ventajas a la hora de exportar o hacer un backup, se generan ficheros .sql inmensos guardando imágenes directo en las tablas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia esto:

```
if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('img')) {

     foreach($this->request->getFileMultiple('img') as $file)
     {   
        $nuevoNombre = $nombreRandom . '-' . $file->getName();
        $file->move('./public/assets/img',$nuevoNombre);

      $data = [
        'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
        'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
        'img' =>  $nuevoNombre
      ];

      $proyectos->insert($data);
     }
}
```

por esto:

```
if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('img')) {
     $imagenes = [];
     foreach($this->request->getFileMultiple('img') as $file)
     {   
        $nuevoNombre = $nombreRandom . '-' . $file->getName();
        $file->move('./public/assets/img',$nuevoNombre);
        $imagenes[] = $nuevoNombre;
     }
     $data = [
        'nombre_proyecto'=> $this->request->getVar('nombre_proyecto'),
        'id_empresa'=> $this->request->getVar('id_empresa'),
        'img' =>  implode(",",$imagenes)
     ];

     $proyectos->insert($data);

}
```

De esta forma solo te generará un único registro donde la columna **img** contendrá los nombres de las imaǵenes separadas por coma gracias a la función [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php).

El día que necesites de nuevo sacar ese dato de la base de datos lo tratarás con [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) para volver a tener las imágenes en un array.

Por ejemplo, si una nueva variable **$imagenes** contiene el valor de la columna **img** de una fila (resultado de una consulta SQL o lo que sea), podrás hacer esto para ponerlas en un array de nuevo y luego tratarlas como quieras:

```
$array_imagenes = explode(",", $imagenes);

foreach($array_imagenes as $img) {
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de nuevo!!! me ha funcionado!